# Determining threat when performing OSINT

Tags: attacks, ip, information-gathering

I am new to ethical hacking and I often find myself really confused when evaluating and determining the danger level of information that can be found regarding a domain when performing OSINT. I'm not sure what information an ethical hacker should be looking for when performing OSINT which may place the web application at risk.

I feel like I over-think the severity of information I find. For example, it's quite simple and easy to retrieve an IP for any domain. The IP can be used to perform a DDoS attack on the domain which will prevent valid users from accessing it and hurt the business but I'm not sure if this is actually dangerous information since most websites will have a security measure such as Cloudflare which has DDoS protection.

Would appreciate any insight into what an ethical hacker should be looking for during the OSINT phase and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use a dip into the Risk pool.

Things are just things until they present a hazard. Whether or not they present a hazard depends on its context. Nothing is inherently a hazard.

If an IP being known represents a *typical* hazard will depend on a few factors. It is not a typical hazard across multiple contexts (IPs tend to be public knowledge for public portals).

You then have to separate the idea that the hazard might have *mitigations* (like CloudFlare). Leave the mitigations aside when considering whether something is a hazard.

And then you should not focus on common hazards for all Internet users (like DDoS). Those hazards are "boilerplate" that would apply to everyone. It's like saying, "the Internet could stop working". While true, it's not a specific threat to them (unless you can show that it is a unique threat in their context).

When writing a report on the specific hazards that a specific target might experience, you want to focus on the unique hazards that exist for them and their context. Everyone knows they could get a DDoS. However, they might have thought that an IP was hidden or not associated with them, but you found the connection. But that's only a hazard if you know (or can guess) that the target hoped to keep that info hidden. Or you might be able to show that the target is *uniquely* vulnerable to a DDoS or being targetted for one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think this makes more sense. What would you say is an example of a threat that could be unique? Something like a physical address? OSINT tools are good at finding physical addresses but I'm not sure if this is a threat since I think it returns the location of the server hosting the website and not the location of the organization itself.

Comment: I would apply the same principle: is the physical address a unique threat? Addresses tend to be public and easily discoverable.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the explanation, really helped me out.